# Restore <p:selectOneMenu> item, while editing

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I bring the `<p:selectOneMenu` item values back while editing.Now it just showing 'Select One', and users have to select the desired one (or already submitted)again. How can I bring that?

Comment: I didn't understand a bit! Please explain your problem a little better...

Comment: I am new to JSF primefaces.Sorry for the question being unclear. Suppose I have a <SelectOneMenu> transportModes (with items car,bike,bus), the user already selected 'bike' as his transportMode. While editing the information again the 'bike' should be populated there in the top instead of '--Select--' of dropdown list. For my case simply dropdown is coming and on update will save a null value.Hope you got the question.

Comment: can you post your <p:selectOneMenu code?

Comment: <h:outputText value="Transport Mode" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="title" value="#employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{employeeView.employeeDTO.trMode}" itemValue='#{employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode}' /<f:selectItem itemLabel="Car" itemValue='1' />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Bus" itemValue='2' />  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bike" itemValue='3' /></p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Yes, post some code... What does it mean `edit the information`? Do you mean navigate away and then go back to the previous page? I tested this and the value of selectOneMenu persisted, now it depends the life cycle of you bean, so post the java and xhtml code!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the first `f:selectItem` of yours

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{employeeView.employeeDTO.trMode}" itemValue='#{employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode}' />
```

the value attribute of the `<p:selectOneMenu` tag will hold the selected value...

and by the way , here are several examples of it : [p:selectOneMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf)

Comment: When I changed itemValue='#{employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode}' to  itemValue=''. Its working. Why is that?

Comment: why did you placed the <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{employeeView.employeeDTO.trMode}" itemValue='#{employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode}' /> in the first place? you are not supposed to place the employeeView.employeeDTO.transportMode , both in the value of the selectOneMenu and in one of the itemValue, take a look in the link I gave you , about how to use the selecpOneMenu propely